# how to prevent resource creation in terraform when refering output of one project wiith common resources in another project

Tags: terraform

In one solution have 2 projects. The common-infra project is for creating ecs cluster and common ecs services like nginx used by all other services. ecs-service1 project contains resource definition for creating ecs services. I do reference resource ARNs created in common-infra project in my ecs-service1 project.

I first go to common-infra and do terraforma plan and create. Now the cluster and nginx service is up and running. Next I go to ecs-service1 and then to terraform plan. At this point it recoganizes the fact that I have linked to a module common-infra and shows that it will create the cluster and common service like nginx again.

Is there a way to arrange/reference the project in such a way that when I run terrafrom plan ecs-service1 it know that common-infra is already built and it knows the state and it only creates only the resoruces in ecs-services1 and only pulling in the ARNs reference created in common-infra?

```
.
├── ecs-service1
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── task-def
│   │   ├── adt-api-staging2-task-definition.json
│   │   └── adt-frontend-staging2-task-definition.json
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   ├── terraform.tfstate.backup
│   └── variables.tf
├── common-infra
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── task-def
│   │   └── my-nginx-staging2-task-definition.json
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   ├── user-data.sh
│   └── variables.tf
└── script
    └── get-taskdefinitions.sh
```

**common-infra main.tf**

```
output "splat_lb_listener_http_80_arn"{
  value = aws_lb_listener.http_80.arn
}

output "splat_lb_listener_http_8080_arn"{
  value = aws_lb_listener.http_8080.arn
}

output "splat_ecs_cluster_arn" {
  value = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.arn
}
```

**ecs-service1 main.tf**

```
module "splat_common" {
  source = "../common-infa"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "frontend_webapp_service" {

    name = var.frontend_services["service_name"]
    cluster = module.splat_common.splat_ecs_cluster_arn 
...
}
```

Comment: You can use , `remote_state_data` datasource to fetch the values from common-infra state to ecs-service pieces.https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote-state-data.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions, but first I'd like to say that your `ecs-service` should be calling `common-infra` as a module only - so that all of the resource creation is handled at once (and not split apart as you describe).

Another solution would be to use `terraform import` to get the current state into your existing terraform. This is less than ideal, because now you have the same infrastructure being managed by 2 state files.

If you are including the `common-infra` because it provides some output, you should look into using `data` lookups (https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html). You can even reference output of other terraform state (https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote-state-data.html) (although I've never actually tried this, it **can** be done).